# Having problem with asynchronous calls in the http module

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

Im trying to recieve thi htttp request and, depending on the data recieved by the request, do different things. After searching around and fiddling for a while with my code i came up with this solution but it is not working and im guessing it is because of my lack of experience dealing with asynchronous code.

Heres the part of the code thats failing me. When i debug, the program doesnt even enters the `req.on('data', function(chunk))` line.

````
const port = process.env.PORT || 1337;
server.listen(port);

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {

    var response; 
    var bool = false;

    if(req.url == "/" ){
        res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
        res.end("Whatsupp");
    } 
    else if (req.url == "/message"){
        let datas = []
        req.on('data', function(chunk){
            datas.push(chunk.toString());
        });
        req.on('end', function(){
            var challenge = JSON.parse(data).challenge;
            var text = JSON.parse(data).event.text;
            if(challenge != undefined){
                bool = true;
                response = challenge.toString();
                console.log(response);
            }
            else if(text != undefined){
                bool = true;
                response = (detectType(text.toString()));
                console.log(response);
            }
            else {
                response = "algun error";
            }
        })
        res.writeHead(bool? (200, {"Content-Type":"text/plain"}): (400, {"Content-Type":"text/plain"}) );
        res.write(response);
    }

});  ```
````

Comment: Please show a tiny bit more code around this function, you're a few lines away from a [mcve]. As for why it's not entering your function: no idea, are you even visiting the correct URL to make it do that? (because you don't mention what _you_ are doing in order to get the code to trigger)

Comment: What `http client` you are using and where is the code that makes the `request`?

Comment: I will add the code, but i am not making requests, i am merely receiving incoming ones. And i can see the url being the correct one. It enters the ```if url == "/message" ``` but it doesn't enter the req.on bit.